# $T(x)=T(y)$, whenever $|x-y|=1/n$

Tags: real-analysis

$\textbf{Question.}$ Let $T:[0.1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $T(0)=T(1)$. Then

- For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ show that there exists, $x,y\in[0,1]$ satisfying $|x-y|=\frac{1}{n}$ and $T(x)=T(y)$.
- Does the above result hold true if $|x-y|=h_n$ for some $h_n$ which is not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$?

It looks like a basic application of the definition of limit, but I am not really sure, where to start or what to look at.
Would be grateful in case of a detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Ramana, and welcome to MSE! First of all, you should know that what you're asking is not true in general, so clearly there's some information you've left out. Also, you should see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question for information on asking homework question; you've broken a few pieces of etiquette. Finally, it's customary for you to show us what progress you've already made so we can help you along :)

Comment: Consider $T(x)=x$, for which the first statement is not true.

Comment: @Vim Sorry, forgot to add a condition, that $T(0)=T(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The question is equivalent to showing that the function $f: [0,1-\frac{1}{n}] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = T(x+\frac{1}{n}) - T(x)$ has a zero.

Suppose $f$ has no zeroes. Then convince yourself that $f$ must be either positive everywhere or negative everywhere (hint: intermediate value theorem).

Suppose $f$ is positive everywhere. Then
$$0<\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) = \cdots = -T(0) +T(1) = 0 $$